# Compact shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to generate a compact shiny dashboard. I have tried different options like renderTable, themes to make the output compact but still the output is very sparse. The tabs are also not looking very disjointed. The dashboard is loosing lot of space in between.

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
custom_theme <- bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    fg = "#000000",
    primary = "#0199F8",
    secondary = "#FF374B",
    base_font = "Maven Pro")
dt_4cyl = data.table(dt_mtcars%>% filter(cyl == 4))
dt_6cyl = dt_mtcars%>% filter(cyl == 6)
dt_8cyl = dt_mtcars%>% filter(cyl == 8)

server_fnl_integeration <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt_4cyl_op <- renderDT(dt_4cyl)
    output$dt_6cyl_op <- renderDT(dt_6cyl)
    output$dt_8cyl_op <- renderDT(dt_8cyl)}

ui_tabPanel_4cyl = tabPanel(tableOutput("dt_4cyl_op"))
ui_tabPanel_6cyl = tabPanel(tableOutput("dt_6cyl_op"))
ui_tabPanel_8cyl = tabPanel(tableOutput("dt_8cyl_op"))

ui_fnl_integeration <- fluidPage(
    theme = custom_theme,
    tags$style(".modal-dialog {max-width: 90vw;}"),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("FourCylinder",
                 tabsetPanel(ui_tabPanel_4cyl)),
        tabPanel("SixCylinder",
                 tabsetPanel(ui_tabPanel_4cyl)),
        tabPanel("EightCylinder",
                 tabsetPanel(ui_tabPanel_8cyl))
    ))


shinyApp(ui =  ui_fnl_integeration, server = server_fnl_integeration)
```

Comment: I agree. This is not going to be satisfying ... learn CSS. Just about everything can be adjusted by stylesheets and such, and there are people who work full-time on CSS and related topics. (I am not proficient with CSS, just enough to not break everything I attempt with CSS :-)

Comment: Any examples to follow as 1)  how to integrate CSS into Shiny 2) which components/code from CSS  to use

Comment: https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/css/, https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/, and https://shiny.posit.co/r/getstarted/build-an-app/customizing-ui/theming.html are the first three on google's list when I searched. I'm not being snarky, but I'm not a pro with CSS (barely passing, tbh), but it's a common enough conversation in [tag:shiny] that you're likely to find a lot of questions/answers and howtos/tutorials with some concerted searches.